# Filter users in OpenLDAP ACL by attribute value

Tags: acl, openldap

I want to give access to users who have attribute with certain value.

Let's say I have `"ou=protected,dc=example,dc=com"` directory and I want it to be writable by any user with `canAccessProtected` attribute set to `TRUE`.

Something like

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=protected,dc=example,dc=com"
by users/canAccessProtected="TRUE" write
```

I've checked documentation and was unable to find a way, although I haven't grasped sets and few other things.

**Is it possible to manage user access by attribute value? If yes, then how?**

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic group like: 
`dn:cn=protectedGroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass:top
objectClass:groupOfURLs
cn:protectedGroup
memberURL: ldap:///ou=users,dc=example,dc=com??sub?(canAccessProtected=TRUE)`

Enable dynlist in your slapd.conf like: 
`overlay dynlist
dynlist-attrset groupOfURLs memberURL member`

Grant write access to the members of that group: 
`access to dn.subtree="ou=protected,dc=example,dc=com"
    by set="[cn=protectedGroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com]/member & user" write`

Add necessary ACL rules as you see fit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find time to check your solution. When I'll get to it, I'll respond.